# Dune Error Building from Sources

Tags: error

I'm trying to build from sources but when I run `$ make` I get the error:

`File "docs/doc_gen/errors/dune", line 15, characters 1-52: 15 | (action (run %{lib:tezos-tooling:lint.sh} %{deps}))) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: 'action' was deleted in version 2.0 of the dune language. Use a rule stanza with the alias field instead make: *** [Makefile:20: all] Error 1`

I think that I have the wrong version of dune (need 1.8.0, have 2.something) but I don't know much about opam and the ocaml ecosystem. How could I go about downgrading my version of dune?
running ubuntu 19.10, I just installed ocaml and opam from apt

P.S. If someone could recommend a good tag for this kind of post that would be great. If one doesn't exist I would suggest adding a devops tag or something.

Comment: Finally figured this out. The problem was installing opam from apt rather than what is stated on this page:

https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html#build-from-sources

Comment: How much work would it be to move over to dune 2? If someone could give me a bit of guidance on how to replace all the times we use that action keyword I can do the legwork.

Comment: Found an issue on the gitlab: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/633

moving this discussion there.

Comment: You should answer your own question with your answer with the details you posted here, it might help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround until `dune` 2 support is implemented is to pin `dune` to an earlier version, i.e.:

```
opam pin dune 1.11.4
```